# determining Preferred Language in OS X via cli

Tags: macos, command-line, defaults, language

I was hoping to do something like:

```
defaults read -g AppleLanguages | awk -F, '/[^(]/{print $1;exit}'
```

but if only one language is listed in "Preferred Languages", then defaults read -g AppleLanguages returns an error:

> The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleLanguages) does not exist

It works fine if multiple languages are listed.
Does anyone have a reliable way of determining the language selected for a given user in OS X?

Comment: [Reposted from Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182083/reliable-method-to-determine-system-language-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the comma.  Conditionally remove the comma if it's there.

```
defaults read -g AppleLanguages | sed -n "2p" | tr -d ,
```